# How many hops do the default implementations of MPI_Reduce and MPI_Allreduce take?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to work out how many separate parallel "hop" phases would typically be involved in MPI_Reduce and MPI_Allreduce, to get a ball-park figure of a minimum latency that would be involved in these operations. Essentially under the assumption that the messages are very small, so latency would dominate(?)

Say, a reduce between between 100 MPI processes. An implementation could take 99 "latencies": each process sending a message to one other. Another implementation could make each process send a message to all other nodes, and would only take 1 amount of "latency" (although yes, can't really imagine it would be so simple: there would be contention that increased this)

Comment: There is no "default implementation" for MPI. In the case of Open MPI, the `coll/tuned` component (likely the default one) selects an algorithm (among several ones) based on communicator and message size.

Comment: The typical algorithms are tree-based which means that the number of messages for P processes will scale as log2(P). This is a huge improvement over the naive "send to all" implementation - even on 1024 processes, you're looking at tens of messages vs over 1000. MPI will have optimisations to do the reductions on a node using shared memory so the effective latency here will be much less. In practice, it's probably the number of nodes that is the most important factor.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the good comment of @GillesGouaillardet, several MPI implementations use a **dynamic/autotuned-based approach**. This is the case of the widely-used [OpenMPI](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/open-mpi/papers/euro-pvmmpi-2004-overview/euro-pvmmpi-2004-overview.pdf) and [MPICH](https://fs.hlrs.de/projects/rabenseifner/publ/HPCA_collectives.pdf) implementations (assuming they are configured correctly). The chosen algorithm can be dependent on several factors (as you can see in the research papers). Even in your specific case: the buffer size matters for example. Latency is not always the limiting factor, especially with few nodes. Furthermore, the **network topology** (eg. fat trees, hypercubes, torus, etc.) and the **interconnect technology** of the nodes have a significant impact on the latency and throughput. An efficient implementation must take that into account to be efficient, mainly to avoid the **contention** of the network. That being said, they are algorithms that can do this in `log(n)` hops (with `n` the number of nodes) on fat-trees/hypercube/butterfly networks (for both collective operations). For torus-based networks, *the number of hops is bounded by the topology* itself and more specifically by the [diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) of the torus which is generally something like `O(n^(1/d))` (with `d` the number of dimensions of the torus).